# IdentityManager (Custom STS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sts-securitytokenservice

**UPDATE:
There was no error in config! The error was that i miss placed the certificate.
Now i get this error: 
ID2057: Cannot construct a X509SigningCredentials instance for a certificate without the private key.
Parameternamn: token
:)**

iam trying to make a CustomSTS following this guide:
[Chris Klug](http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/04/09/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)

When i run my customSTS on IIS 7 With url: http://identitymanager.dev/ everything works.
I login and gets redirected to the customSTS's home controller.

*But the problem is when i use my relying application.*

**It redirects to this url:**

http://identitymanager.dev/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2fIdentityManager.dev%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252f&wct=2013-06-29T20%3a54%3a41Z&wreply=http%3a%2f%2fIdentityManager.dev%2f

**And i get this error msg:**
No certificate was found for subject Name cn=IdentityManager.dev

The thing is i have a cert with name IdentityManager.dev (For my user account) when i check mmc.exe.

**Stacktrace:**
[image: Stacktrace]

Here is my web.config for the customSTS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="IssuerName" value="http://IdentityManager.dev/" />
    <add key="SigningCertificateName" value="cn=IdentityManager.dev" />
    <add key="EncryptionCertificate" value="" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**And here is my FederationMetaData:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EntityDescriptor ID="_70a250d5-e3e1-494a-a392-7ed1736f3180"   entityID="http://IdentityManager.dev/" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
  <RoleDescriptor xsi:type="fed:SecurityTokenServiceType" protocolSupportEnumeration="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fed="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706">
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <X509Data>
          <X509Certificate><!--- My Cert code here --></X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <ContactPerson contactType="administrative">
      <GivenName>Stefan Karlsson</GivenName>
    </ContactPerson>
    <fed:ClaimTypesOffered>
      <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Name</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>The name of the subject.</auth:Description>
      </auth:ClaimType>
      <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Role</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>The role of the subject.</auth:Description>
      </auth:ClaimType>
    </fed:ClaimTypesOffered>
    <fed:SecurityTokenServiceEndpoint>
      <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <Address>http://IdentityManager.dev/</Address>
      </EndpointReference>
    </fed:SecurityTokenServiceEndpoint>
    <fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
      <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <Address>http://IdentityManager.dev/</Address>
      </EndpointReference>
    </fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
  </RoleDescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

**And here is my RELYING app web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="http://IdentityManager.dev/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Issuer" value="http://IdentityManager.dev/" />
    <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="productionSTS" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:2093/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
      <!--<add thumbprint="1C3A3728344BCC7E812A54B95C49BE7840132DD8" name="https://humanytest.accesscontrol.windows.net/" />-->
          <add thumbprint="7796E0E0B576EBC2406E6BE8A259318E3761C759" name="http://IdentityManager.dev/" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://IdentityManager.dev/" realm="http://localhost:2093/" reply="http://localhost:2093/" requireHttps="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Relying FederationMetaData:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EntityDescriptor ID="_8d7c3e01-5bc5-4719-9863-0b687aa54cd8" entityID="http://IdentityManager.dev/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml/" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
  <RoleDescriptor xsi:type="fed:ApplicationServiceType" xmlns:fed="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" protocolSupportEnumeration="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <fed:TargetScopes>
      <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Address>http://identitymanager.dev/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml/</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:EndpointReference>
      <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Address>http://localhost:2093/</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:EndpointReference>
    </fed:TargetScopes>
    <fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
      <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Address>http://identitymanager.dev/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml/</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:EndpointReference>
    </fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
  </RoleDescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now its working for me,
Mention right parameters for "Store name" and "Store location" while getting the store,

```
        public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string subjectName)
        {
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

Comment: For future readers: Check out this question and "blowdart" AND "Nigel Shaw" answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786019/where-did-my-certificate-store-go